# How to import all tables with sqoop from SQL Server when tables are in different schemas?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

When I try to import all tables from SQL Server in hive with sqoop, it works but only when tables are in default schema (`dbo`).

When tables are in different schema (and there are multiple schemas), import fails with error:

```
 15/09/12 16:47:50 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
Invalid object name 'Carveout'.
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Carveout'.
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:674)
         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:683)
         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:223)
         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:347)
         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1277)
         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1089)
         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportAllTablesTool.run(ImportAllTablesTool.java:105)
         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import all tables of a particular schema.

Try -- -schema schemaName at the end.

I cannot guarantee this in case you are creating a job.

Comment: but i have multiple tables and multiple schemas

Comment: You could list all the tables one after the other in a line with respective schema in a file, read the file and use the Sqoop API method to ingest all the tables one by one. This way you can ingest all table data in one execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the table list as schemaname.dbo.tablename..iterate on it while sqoop import and use this in --query select *from schemaname.dbo.tablename